# Fail to compile and run the c++ code with gcc48

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, makefile

I have cloned someone's c++ code from github but failed to compile it. The author told me that he could successfully run it with gcc 4.8.4. So I installed gcc48 using `homebrew` and specify the version of `gcc` in the `makefile` placed in his code folder.

Here is the setting in Makefile:

```
CC=g++-4.8
CFLAGS=-c -pipe -O3
#INCLUDE=-I /home/xh/jianguoyun/my/code/cpp/mylib
MODEL_EXE=bbtm infer

all:$(MODEL_EXE) 

bbtm:BurstyBTM.o main.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

infer:infer.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

mail.o:BurstyBTM.h
BurstyBTM.o:BurstyBTM.h biterm.h doc.h
infer.o:infer.h doc.h

%.o:%.cpp
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ 

clean:
    rm -rf *.o $(MODEL_EXE)
```

However, an error is got during the compile:

```
g++-4.8  -c -pipe -O3 BurstyBTM.cpp -o BurstyBTM.o 
BurstyBTM.cpp: In member function 'Pvec<double> BurstyBTM::compute_pz_b(Biterm&)':
BurstyBTM.cpp:129:23: error: could not convert 'pz.Pvec<T>::normalize<double>(0.0)' from 'void' to 'Pvec<double>'
   return pz.normalize();
                       ^
BurstyBTM.cpp: In member function 'void BurstyBTM::save_pz(std::string)':
BurstyBTM.cpp:158:41: error: conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'Pvec<double>' requested
   Pvec<double> pz = nb_z.normalize(alpha);
                                         ^
BurstyBTM.cpp: In member function 'void BurstyBTM::save_pw_z(std::string)':
BurstyBTM.cpp:164:37: error: conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'Pmat<double>' requested
   Pmat<double> pw_z = nwz.normr(beta);
                                     ^
make: *** [BurstyBTM.o] Error 1
```

I have tried to install gcc49 and run it again but also failed. I guess it is not because of the error of code as the author said he could run it with no errors. My os is os x 10.10. Could you please help me to solve this problem? I am nearly mad about this. Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

Here is the linkage to [github](https://github.com/xiaohuiyan/BurstyBTM/)

And the code with errors are as below:

```
for (int k = 1; k < K + 1; ++k) {
  double deno = 2 * nb_z[k] + W * beta;
  double pw1k = (nwz[k][w1] + beta) / deno;
  double pw2k = (nwz[k][w2] + beta) / (deno + 1);
  double pk_t = (nb_z[k] + alpha) / (nb + K * alpha);
  pz[k] = eta * pk_t * pw1k * pw2k;
}

return pz.normalize();
}

void BurstyBTM::save_pz(string pt) {
Pvec<double> pz = nb_z.normalize(alpha);
pz.write(pt);
}


void BurstyBTM::save_pw_z(string pt) {
Pmat<double> pw_z = nwz.normr(beta);
pw_z.write(pt);
}
```

Comment: Posting the contents of the makefile but not the code! How can anybody help you figure out what's wrong?

Comment: We need to see some code. What is `beta` or `alpha`? Are they `Pvec<double>`?

Comment: I think it is quite feasible from your error messages that, the error lies in methods in "BurstyBTM.cpp". It has no relation with the Makefile.

Comment: Apparently the compiler believes that the functions `normalize` and `normr` are declared with a `void` return type. So, are they?

Comment: Yes, they are indeed: https://github.com/xiaohuiyan/BurstyBTM/blob/master/src/pvec.h

Comment: @RSahu Sorry, as there are many code in the folder, i dont' know to post which piece. Now i have posted the github address and those lines of code that the errors point to. Please tell me if any other one you want to take a look.

Comment: @huu Could you please take a look at [here](https://github.com/xiaohuiyan/BurstyBTM/blob/master/script/runExample.sh) In the line 8 and line 9 there are declaration. But I am not quite sure whether they are.

Comment: @BoPersson it seems to be, please take a look at [line 314](https://github.com/xiaohuiyan/BurstyBTM/blob/master/src/pmat.h)

Answer (score 0):

At least the first error BurstyBTM.cpp:129:23 is indeed a coding error and the compiler is right - in pvec.h the Pvec::normalize is defined with void as the return type.

Didn't check the other ones but I suppose it is the same kind of error and I'm wondering how the author even managed to compile it (it will definitely not compile with g++ and MSVC).

Comment: Not only the author said it could be run successfully. Another guy said he could run it in Linux without errors. I am using os x 10.10.